# Can you set up a private Azure-like "web/worker role" PaaS cloud on-premises with Microsoft technology?

Tags: cloud

It's so hard to google for the answer to this question because I get a bagillion hits about using Azure and *hints* that PaaS is supported for private data centers, but no concrete information.

I'm just looking for someone to say, "Yeah, read up on Microsoft Product X.... you're looking for their Y feature."

Thanks!

Comment: Wow... so this seems pretty definitive that MS does not support PaaS in a private data center.  I've never had this much silence on a StackExchange site.

Comment: I also have the same question? Did you figure out the answer for this?

Comment: I have seen nothing.  However, I am certain that Win2012 and Microsoft Virtual Machine Manager are going to make this a reality "soon".  Also, at the time I wrote this, I wasn't aware of how amazing the MSDN benefits were for Azure, so I am actually for some of the things that I wanted a private PaaS for.